# ms access 2003 navigate to absolute position of record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to navigate to a record on a form by entering the records absolute position in a textbox. So far miserable failure. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Is there some reason why the default Access navigation controls don't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recordset, or recordsetclone:

```
Set RS = frm.RecordsetClone
''Populate recordset
RS.MoveLast
RS.MoveFirst

If lngRecNo = 0 Or lngRecNo > RS.RecordCount Then
    MsgBox "Cannot go to the specified record." & vbCrLf _
    & "Please try again."
Else
    ''Counting from zero
    RS.AbsolutePosition = lngRecNo - 1
    frm.Bookmark = RS.Bookmark
End If
```

Comment: Why set a recordset variable instead of just using a WITH block for the RecordsetClone?

Comment: Because I reckon you can use something like this for all forms, just pass the form as a form and the required position as long.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, as you can use frm.RecordsetClone for your WITH block (as opposed to Me.RecordsetClone).